# Why is it called 'Time.zone.local' instead of 'Time.zone.new'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It seems that [`Time.zone.local`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-local) does exactly what you would think `Time.zone.new` would do. Although, `Time.zone.new` does not exist. Why does this peculiar naming deviate from the standard?

Update: 
The question is about understanding why Rails presumably deviates from the convention of using `.new` when instantiating a new object of some particular type. By using for example `Time.zone.local(2013,10,1)` instead of i.e. `Time.zone.new(2013,10,1)` to get a `TimeWithZone` object.

Comment: Are you referring to [`now`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-now) instead of `new`?

Comment: @ndn Not on `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` but on `Time`, correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: How can you think that a non-existing method would do something? I don't get it.

Comment: What is "the standard" that you are mentioning? It is not clear at all.

Comment: @schmijos no, I'm not referring to `now`.

Comment: @kabanus Why do you think it has nothing to do with programming? It's about understanding why Rails deviates from the convention of using `.new` when instantiating a new object of some particular type.

Comment: @sawa The `Time.zone.local` method exists, but I think it should rather be named `Time.zone.new`, since the standard is to instantiate new objects by using `new`.

Comment: On second thought perhaps your right, especially seeing the edit and the answer. You did get some heat for this question though, so I guess I wasn't the only one confused. Removed my close vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every method which returns a new value is called `new`.

In general, it is expected that `new` is always a method on a class which returns a new instance of said class. With `Time.zone.local` however, `Time.zone` is not a class but an instance of `ActiveSupport::TimeZone`. Defining it as `new` would be quite misleading since it would imply that `Time.zone` returns a class and not an object instance.

Thus, `ActiveSupport::TimeZone#local` is a sensible name for the method to create a new `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` instance in the "local" (i.e. chosen) timezone. In the usual Rails context where you would set `Time.zone` [to the current user's timezone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-zone-3D), the pattern of calling `Time.zone.local(...)` thus makes it clear what is happening here: to create a new Time-like object in the user's local timezone.

Comment: It would also imply that `Time.zone.new` would return an instance of the `Time.zone` class, i.e. a `TimeZone` instance instead of a `TimeWithZone` instance.